# ASP.NET Boilerplate supports Nhibernate NETCore 2.0?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Would like to develop project with Angular, WebAPI and NHibernate;
Does ABP supports NHibernate under NETCore 2.0 ?

Comment: No, [net461](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/922b2fb895b8cdd072e7353a6a3b2ebe77bfa25e/src/Abp.NHibernate/Abp.NHibernate.csproj#L6) only.

Comment: @aaron, since Abp.NHibernate is currently target NHibernate 5.1.1 (which also support NETCore 2.0); then it is possible to re-target Abp.NHibernate to support NETCore 2.0 ? or possibly create Abp.NHibernate.Core ?

Comment: You are welcome to submit a PR or make a feature request at the repo.